# What could cause a PDF file to render differently in browser on initial request?

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, pdf, flask, reportlab

I'm using python (flask) and reportlab to generate and send a PDF file to the browser. For some reason, when the file is initially sent to the browser (Chrome) a text string is not aligned properly to how it is generated on the page. Only when I reload the page does it render properly. This only happens for certain PDF files and only on Chrome. If I open the file in acrobat or render it in Mozilla it renders fine.